# Can GNU APL output be sent to a command line plotting program (e.g., gnuplot)?

Tags: apl

I would like to plot the output of GNU APL calculations using open-source plotting software (e.g., gnuplot) that takes commandline input but I don't see how it is possible with the available system commands and functions.  The )HOST command allows running system commands but I don't understand how the output or variables can be redirected from the terminal display to the commandline.

Not as desirable, but still OK would be to save output or variables to files that could be read by the plotting software. However, the only file-saving options I see relate to workspaces.

Two solutions I am not seeking are:
1) ASCII character plots
2) Running GNU APL as a script that sends output to stdout but would not be interactive APL.

Thanks for your suggestions!

Comment: I just implemented support for basic plotting to gnuplot in gnu-apl-mode for Emacs. It also supports exporting arrays to CSV that input into gnuplot if now flexibility is needed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe you can write the result into some file using AP210 and then start gnuplot with the filename using )HOST or AP100.

I have added examples of how to use AP100 and AP210 to the src/testcases directory in the SVN repository for GNU APL. A more complete description of these APs can be found in the IBM documents for APL2 that can be found at:

http://www.catpad.net/michael/apl/ibmapl2/

/// Jürgen